# pass ng-value data to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is a field that filters ng-value and the input field has ng-model. When the the ng-value data is printed, the value is undefined.
snippet below:

```
<input ng-model="schoolWordsCaption"  
              class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-value="schoolWords | words" readonly>

alert($scope.schoolWordsCaption) //prints undefined
```

at the moment, words is a directive coming from the controller but the fact is the data gotten from ng-value is not reachable to ng-model as seen from the alert.

Comment: why are you using ng-vlaue in input type text when you can do anything using ng-model?

Comment: please share your controller